# bash скрипт структурирования файлов

Tags: linux, bash

Может у кого подобный скрипт завалялся? 
Есть директория с большим количеством файлов с разной датой создания, надо на каждую существующую дату создать каталог, в который переместить файлы с соответствующей датой создания.

Answer (score 2):

С датой создания есть проблема - не все файловые системы ее правильно сохраняют. [детально](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91197/how-to-find-creation-date-of-file)

создайте скрипт scr.sh, который умеет "перемешать файл на место"

```
#/usr/bin/bash
DIR=$(stat -c '%x' $1 | cut -f 1 -d ' ')
mkdir -p $DIR
mv $1 $DIR/
```

А дальше просто запустите

```
find ~/ -name "*.png" -exec bash scr.sh {} \;
```

я выбрал перемещать только png файлы, но тут Ваше дело. Настоятельно рекомендую написать вначале не mv, а cp.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл полезный скрипт с блога kubuntu у товарища под ником dm

```
#!/bin/bash
# Скрипт раскладывает фотографии по каталогам вида гггг/мм, изменяет разрешение и качество в 
# соответствии с заданными параметрами, а так же переименовывает изображения в формат 
# гггг-мм-дд_чч-мм-сс.jpg
# На пример: /mnt/DCIM/IMG-20131014112354.jpg -> $HOME/Photo/2013/10/2013-10-14_11-23-54.jpg
#
# Данные о дате снимка ищутся в следующем порядке:
# 1) Exif данные (Exif.Photo.DateTimeOriginal и Exif.Image.DateTime)
# 2) В названии фотографии. Распознает различные варианты написания даты
# 3) Из даты создания файла
#
# При запуске без аргументов обрабатывает текущий каталог и все его подкаталоги. В качестве аргумента 
# можно указать другой рабочий каталог-источник.
# НЕ удаляет оригиналы изображений!
# НЕ увеличивает разрешение
# Для работы необходим пакет exiv2 (sudo apt-get install exiv2)
##################################

src_dir=${1-`pwd`}  # По умолчанию используется текущий каталог
dst_dir=$HOME/Photo # Каталог в который будут скопированны обработанные фотографии
quality=80          # Качество JPG изображения
resize=1600x900     # Размер после конвертации

# Ищем JPG файлы в указанной папке
#find "$src_dir" -iname "*.jpg" -print0 | sort | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0'     file ; do

# Ищем JPG файлы в указанной папке и всех подпапках!
find "$src_dir" -iname "*.jpg" | sort | while IFS= read -r file ; do

  # Пробуем взять дату из Exif.Photo.DateTimeOriginal или Exif.Image.DateTime
  for photo_date in "Exif.Photo.DateTimeOriginal" "Exif.Image.DateTime" ; do
    photo_date=$(exiv2 -g "$photo_date" -Pv "$file")
    if [ -n "$photo_date" ] ; then  # Если дата найдена, прекращаем перебор
      break
    fi
  done

  if [ -z "$photo_date" ] ; then # Если в exif дата не найдена ищем в названии файла

    # Ищем дату в названии файла и приводим её к виду ггггммддччммсс
    photo_date=$(basename "$file" ".jpg" | egrep -o -m1 [0-9]\{4\}\([-_:\ ]?[0-9]\)\{10\})
      if [ -n "$photo_date" ] ; then

    # Приводим дату к виду гггг:мм:дд чч:мм:сс для корректного добавляения в exif
photo_date=$(echo "$photo_date" | tr -d "\_\-\:\ " | sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1:\2:\3 \4:\5:/')

# Добавляем дату из названия файла в exif
exiv2 -M"add Exif.Image.DateTime Ascii "$photo_date"" "$file"

  else # Если даты в названии не нашли, берем дату изменения (создания) файла
photo_date=$(date +"%Y:%m:%d %T" -r "$file")
#exiv2 -M"add Exif.Image.DateTime Ascii $photo_date" "$file"
  fi
  fi

  # Приводим различные вариации даты к единому виду гггг мм дд чч мм сс
  photo_date=$(echo "$photo_date" | egrep -o -m1 [0-9]\{4\}\([-_:\ ]?[0-9]\)\{10\} | tr -d "\_\-\:\ " | sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 /')

  # Разбиваем полученную дату (гггг мм дд чч мм сс) на фрагменты
  # $1 - Год, $2 - Месяц, $3 - День, $4 - Час, $5 - Минута, $6 - Секунда
  set -- $photo_date

  mkdir -p "$dst_dir/$1/$2" # Создаем структуру папок гггг/мм

  # Копируем фотографию, только если исходный файл новее существующего или отсутствует. При копировании сохраняется дата создания фотографии
  #cp -uvp "$file" "$dst_dir/$1/$2/$1-$2-$3_$4-$5-$6.jpg"

  # Изменяем качество и размер фотографий, переименовываем и копируем в папку назначения
  convert -quality "$quality" -resize "$resize"\> -verbose "$file" "$dst_dir/$1/$2/$1-$2-$3_$4-$5-$6.jpg"

  # Устанавливаем дату создания файла такую же как и дата в exif
  touch -t "$1$2$3$4$5.$6" "$dst_dir/$1/$2/$1-$2-$3_$4-$5-$6.jpg"

done

exit 0
```

Comment: если нужно просто переименовать фотографии и разложить по папкам не проводя над ними никаких действий, типа изменения разрешения и изменения степени сжатия, то можно просто закомментировать в скрипте строку:
convert -quality "$quality" -resize "$resize"\> -verbose "$file" "$dst_dir/$1/$2/$1-$2-$3_$4-$5-$6.jpg"

и раскомментировать (убрать # из начала строки) строку:
cp -uvp "$file" "$dst_dir/$1/$2/$1-$2-$3_$4-$5-$6.jpg"

тогда файлы будут просто скопированы с исходными параметрами (разрешение, качество и т.д.)

Comment: Артём, для этого в той же Ubuntu есть очень мощный скрипт renrot (в одноимённом пакете, http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/renrot.1p.html). Там можно очень многое делать, включая вашу начальную задачу.